# Is there a French phrase to say 'I wouldn't put anything past her'?

Tags: expressions, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

I want to write a short message addressed to a friend of mine. Unfortunately my French is not good enough to come up with a French phrase to say the phrase put in italics.

> It was luck and luck alone that made me wise up to her little schemes. Now *I wouldn't put anything past her*.

The message isn't anything formal.

Answer (score 14):

In a casual setting among friends, I'd probably say:

> Si je me suis rendu compte de ce qu'elle manigançait, c'est grâce à un coup de chance, rien d'autre. **Je ne m'étonne plus de rien de sa part** / **avec elle**.

There are various ways to express the idea, and though not a literal translation, this one comes naturally to me.

Comment: "Plus rien ne m'étonne(rait) de sa part" is another way to say the same thing.

Comment: And as a native speaker, @Hawker65 is more idiomatic for this particular construction. The emphasis is on her and her actions, not on your reactions.

Comment: The English idiom "wouldn't put anything past her" has not been rendered properly: it is used to mean that you **think** that someone is **capable** of doing something illegal, mean, criminal ; it is not used to say that someone **has** done something, illegal, mean or criminal.

Answer (score 13):

Since it's "not anything formal", I would say it like this:

> J'ai compris à quoi elle jouait purement par chance. Depuis, je sais qu'**il faut s'attendre à tout venant d'elle**.

Comment: I honestly couldn't tell you if there's a rule that forces a comma here. To me, it looks fine with or without one and I've searched the internet for "s'attendre à tout, venant", it pops up almost always without comma. But it's the internet, so you know. You could also use "avec elle" which doesn't really change anything but flows a little better which would further decrease the need for a comma in my opinion

Answer (score 10):

Ce n'est que la chance, rien d'autre que la chance qui ait fait que je puisse me rendre compte de ses petits plans de supercherie; depuis je la crois capable de tout.

late addition as the result of the remarks of 200_success and user17522

*This next translation might be prefered;*

Ce n'est que la chance, rien d'autre que la chance qui ait fait que je puisse me rendre compte de ses petits plans de supercherie; depuis je la crois capable du pire.

Comment: "Je la crois capable de tout", on its own, does not necessarily have the negative connotation of "I wouldn't put anything past her".

Comment: quite true, good idea; as is my sentence it is unambiguous (200_success) but some reinforcement of it can do it no harm. (I made an addition.)